# Suppress group based on if value exists in record

Tags: crystal-reports

What I would like to do is either suppress a group or (if possible) write this in to a selection record.

The goal would be to display all records in the group if any one of the records in the group meet the requirements.

For example if my group has three records and my requirement is that one of the records have a specific value in one field. Then display all three records in that group. Otherwise, if none of the three have that value then suppress the group.

I know where I need to put the formula and I thought the following would work but instead it only gave me the records that met the requirement not the others that accompany it.

Placed in the suppress group formula field:

```
if {table.field} <> "1" then true else false
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I should mention the group is based on date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I got it figured out. Here's what I did:

1. Create a **Formula Field** to check if the value exists in the record as follows:

   `if {table.field} = "X" then 1`
2. Create a **Summary Field** of the formula field just created and **sum** the total for the formula field effectively counting how many records in that group have the value sought after.
3. Go to **Section Expert** for the desired group and **Suppress** using the following formula.

   `if Sum ({@Formula}, {table.field_2}) < 1 then true`